# UITextField not responding

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i have created a view programmatically. With in that i have added label and text field. But When i tap on text field, text field is not working. It is not even call its delegate methods. Please help on this.

in for Loop i am calling this return method for creating Text field

```
widgetsView.addSubview(createTextFieldForDropDown(entity,ival:i,ypos: posY))
```

//Method to create view with text field and lable

```
func createTextFieldForDropDown(entity:ListingCategoryFeaturesEntity,ival:Int,ypos:CGFloat) -> UIView
    {
        var posY = ypos
        var posX = CGFloat(0)
        let width = (SCREEN_WIDTH/2)-15
        var height = CGFloat(40)

        let viewRadio = UIView()
        viewRadio.frame = CGRectMake(posX, posY, width, height)
        viewRadio.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        height = 40

        posY = 0

        let lblTitle = UILabel()
        lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(posX, posY, width, height)
        lblTitle.text = entity.strDisplayName
                lblTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        lblTitle.font = GRAPHICS.FONT_REGULAR(16)
        viewRadio.addSubview(lblTitle)

        let tag = 9000
        posX = lblTitle.frame.maxX+10

        var textField = UITextField()
        textField.frame = CGRectMake(posX, posY, width, height)
        textField = returnTextFieldsProperties(textField, placeHolderText: "", tagValue: tag+ival)
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        viewRadio.addSubview(textField)


        return viewRadio
    }
```

//Method to retrun text field properties

```
func returnTextFieldsProperties(textField : UITextField ,placeHolderText : String ,tagValue : Int) -> UITextField
    {
        textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:placeHolderText,
            attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColorFromRGB(colorLightGray, alpha: 1.0)])
        textField.font = GRAPHICS.FONT_REGULAR(14)
        textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        textField.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.userInteractionEnabled = true
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next
        let view_left = UIView()
        view_left.frame =  CGRectMake(20,0,10,textField.frameHeight)
        textField.leftView = view_left
        textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        textField.autocorrectionType = .No
        textField.tag = tagValue
        return textField
    }
```

Comment: If i add a text field directly is working. But i need to create all in dynamic.. Please help me on this

Comment: Try setting `viewRadio.userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: No it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove:

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

This may be the problem since you have all your text fields marked with that, but what you want, I assume, is that only the text field that you tapped should be a first responder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not set the delegate method, check the below used in your project,

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

if you create the textfield initially set the delegate method is,

```
var textField = UITextField()
textField.frame = CGRectMake(posX, posY, width, height)
textField = returnTextFieldsProperties(textField, placeHolderText: "", tagValue: tag+ival)

**textField.delegate = self**

textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
viewRadio.addSubview(textField)
```

hope its helpful

Comment: I ve added delegate and its methods. I have another set of textfields out of this method, that is working fine. but this is the textfield which it is not hitting the delegate

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `textField` is not within the bounds of its superview `viewRadio`.  Make the `viewRadio` wide enough to hold both the label and the textView:

Change:

```
viewRadio.frame = CGRectMake(posX, posY, width, height)
```

to:

```
viewRadio.frame = CGRectMake(posX, posY, SCREEN_WIDTH, height)
```

Comment: I try changing the width. but still it is not

Comment: I suggested an easier change to your original code.  Make sure you start with the code you posted above.

Answer (score 0):

> Simple answer, just write delegate method and set delegate of UITextField in storyboard or manually in viewDidLoad

**Write something like this, And It will work Perfectly.**

```
extension LoginVC : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```